# I am stuck with regexp only returning the match while I want to get the followup followed by the match

Tags: regex, tcl, tk-toolkit

TCL/TK:

Problem: I want to be able to get the post-match string data, but even though I provide
regexp with more than a variable for the match itself the secutive variables either turn out empty, or I got the same value from the first two.

E.g:

```
set args "!do dance"
regsub -all {(!do)} $args prefix command
puts $prefis "!do"
puts $command "!do"
```

What to do? Ty

EDIT I found the solution thanks to inspiration by your answer, here's a snippet

```
if { [ regsub {(!do\s+)} $args "" match ] >= 1 } {

if  { $match == "{help}" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the "!do" then you can do the following:

```
set args "!do dance" 
regsub -all {(!do)} $args "" output
puts $output
```

Comment: puts $output gives me " dance". I need to get rid of the prefix space!

Comment: add in last line: % set output [string trim $output]

Comment: As Jerry says, if you're trying to just get the 2nd element of the list, then use lindex. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. regsub may not be the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using regexp here, and it seems like you're using eggdrop or something. You can easily use:

```
set prefix [lindex $args 0]
set command [lindex $args 1]
```

Though you should be careful with `$args`. It's usually used in `proc`s to mean all the other arguments passed on to the `proc` aside from the already defined arguments.

```
% puts $prefix
!do
% puts $command
dance
```